# I want to be able to scroll horizontally when an element is hidden by a component implemented in translate3d

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am implementing a sidebar with translate3d.
It generally worked well, but I would like to enable horizontal scrolling when the element is hidden, as shown below. Do you have any good ideas?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-un8bvw?file=components%2FTlanslateBar.vue

I made a sidebar where tlanslate3d is given by pressing the button.

When the sidebar is displayed, the elements below are hidden

I want to be able to scroll horizontally when the element is hidden

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TlanslateBar :is-show="isShow" />
    {{ isShow }}
    <button @click="isShow = !isShow">click</button>
    <Under />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const isShow = ref(true);
</script>
```

components/Under.vue

```
<template>
  <p>
    testtesttesttesttesttesttestetststesttetesttesttesttesttetesttesttesttesttetesttesttesttestte
  </p>
  <p></p>
</template>

<script setup></script>
```

components/TranslateBar.vue

```
<template>
  <div :style="style" class="side-bar">side-bar</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  isShow: { default: false },
});

const style = computed(() => {
  return {
    transform: props.isShow
      ? 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)'
      : 'translate3d(300px, 0px, 0px)',
  };
});
</script>

<style>
.side-bar {
  width: 300px;
  height: calc(100% - 59px);
  right: 0;
  bottom: 59px;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: $border;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s 0s ease;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please post the code within the question itself instead of linking to an external sandbox